# Git - Changes in two branches, both wrong

Tags: git

I can find answers to similar scenarios, but not exactly this.

I had checked out branch B. I made a load of changes and added a lot of files.

I then needed to make a quick fix to the stable code on branch A. I forgot to commit on branch b before checking out branch A.

I made the fix on branch A and did a `git add -a`, `git commit`. I then noticed all the new files I had added on branch B had now been committed on branch A (I didn't realize git worked like this). The new files have now disappeared from branch B where they should be.

I looked up on how to fix, so I reverted the commit on branch A.

I only really know how to use TFS properly if you are wondering why I am such an idiot.

How can I get my branch B back to how it was? I don't mind making the quick fix on branch A again.

Comment: Which command did you use to revert your last commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, preserve the changes to the branch A that you have dropped. You may use `git reflog` to see "orphaned" commits including the one you have just reverted. Use `git branch tmpA <commit-from-git-reflog>`. Now you have a (temporary) branch `tmpA` with all your changes (hopefully all)

Then you need to fix your `A` branch. You should checkout you A branch (`git checkout A`), then you may re-apply  changes from `tmpA` w/o committing. the basic command is `git cherry-pick --no-commit <tmpA>` but you may use `git gui` or an alternative GUI client to inspect commit graph.

After `git cherry-pick --no-commit ...` you have your changes applied to the working tree and scheduled to be committed but not actually committed. You should inspect the changes (again via `git gui` or `git add -i` if you prefer console). You may add and remove scheduled changes (please note that the working tree is left intact, only records what to be committed on a next commit are changed).

When you finish with selecting appropriate changes to the branch `A`, you should commit them and switch to the branch `B`. Again `git cherry-pick --no-commit tmpA`, inspect the changes and add/remove them from the git index where git records what to be committed.

When you complete the restoration you may remove the temporary branch with `git branch -D tmpA`

Comment: Thank you. Ok, as I was aware of my own incompetence, I made a back up of branch B before I made any changes to branch A. Sounds like it might be easier to just copy that over? I didn't realise it would be so complicated. I obviously need to do a lot of reading up, but in this case, was it my workflow that was wrong? I can see myself switching between branches and forgetting to commit a lot (not an issue on TFS) and don't want to keep running into this issue.

Comment: usually git prevents one from switching branches with uncommitted changes in the working tree if such a switch would overwrite the changes, so you may safely assume that changes won't be "silently lost". Your case is slightly more complicated: you mixed changes for two branches in a single working tree. Again with git it's not a real problem because you may select changes to be committed in the next commit on line by line basis (not even a file by file basis). But certainly you need some work to properly resolve the current mess.

Comment: I'm sure after gaining some git experience you will handle such a situation (in fact it's a "normal working situation") quite easily, it's just a matter of the "fingers memory" (i.e. the experience level which allows one to automatically perform routine actions w/o even concentrating on details)

Answer (score 0):

Let XXX be the SHA of your commit on branch A

( you can get this by

```
git checkout A
git log
```

)

Execute the following

```
git checkout B
git cherry-pick XXX -n
git reset HEAD .
```

This picks the changes from the commit XXX and applies them to the current state. This will contain all changes you need in B, but also the small fix to A. Next, undo this quick fix and your working directory is as you asked

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly that, but I got only a few of the files back and loads of errors about unmerged files.